# Rewrite rule problems in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm really having a headache with these Rewriterules

```
1. RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&cat=$2&page=$3   [QSA]
2. RewriteRule ^article/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA]

3. RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
```

They load

```
..domain.comcategory/...

..domain.comarticle/....

..domain.comsearch/....
```

Instead of the SLASH / between (eg) .COM and CATEGORY
I mean

```
..domain.com/category/...

..domain.com/article/....

..domain.com/search/....
```

The bizzare thing is they all load the pages niceky if the slashes(/) are manually inserted.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in the missing initial slash.  Example:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /category.php?id=$1&cat=$2&page=$3 [QSA]
```

Comment: working preoperly now. Had something to do with the config too. thanks